# regex remove everything between 2 strings

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex for my replaceAll that removes everything between 2 strings and the strings themselves.

For example if I had something like.

```
stackoverflow is really awesome/nremove123/n I love it
```

I was trying to do a replaceAll like this line.replaceAll("/n*/n", ""); This should result in

```
stackoverflow is really awesome I love it
```

I thought the asterisk meant anything but can't get it to work?

cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the `.` means any character. `*` means any number of the previous things. So anything is `.*`.
What you need is

```
/n.*/n
```

If you want to leave an empty space between words use this instead

```
replaceAll("/n.*/n *", " ")
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work for `stackoverflow is really awesome/nremove123/nI love it` however. Where the `I` is next to the `/n`

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work ? Do you mean that it doesn't add a space between /n and I ? If you replace something by an empty string (""), it can't really add extra spaces, it just put an empty string instead

Comment: The result I get back is `stackoverflow is really awesome/nremove123/nI love it` I need it to work with no space. Cheers

Comment: @Decrypter - a little experimentation (in your case) might be in order.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a dot:

replaceAll("/n.*/n")

Answer (score 2):

This will remove anything between `ab`.

```
replaceAll("ab([;\s\w\"\=\,\:\./\~\{\}\?\!\-\%\&\#\$\^\(\)]*?)ab","");
```

Please add any special character, if I'm missing it.