# Regex to remove everything between two strings but with repetitions

Tags: java, regex

Example string: `Before text, <ref>{{BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH}}</ref> after text, <ref>{{reference2}}</ref> end of paragraph.`

I'm looking to remove any mention of `<ref>` and `</ref>` and everything in between.

The result that I want from above example string: `Before text, after text, end of paragraph.`

I have read [regex remove everything between 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660541/regex-remove-everything-between-2-strings) and have tried `replaceAll("<ref>.*</ref>", "")`, the problem I'm having is that the method in that thread is removing too much.  If I use this method on the above text the result will be : `Before text, end of paragraph`.  It will cut out the text in-between the sets of `<ref>` tags.

Is there an easy regex way to achieve the desired result?  In my actual text there might be many (more than 2) sets of `<ref>` `</ref>` tags with useful text in-between.

Edit: added the regex I tried.

Comment: Could you post the regex you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going off the answer in the referenced question you're indeed "removing too much" because the answer uses a greedy operator, use `*?` for a [**non-greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) match instead ...

I would propose the following regular expression if you must use one at all:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?s)<ref>.*?</ref>", "");
```

**Note:** The inline `(?s)` mode modifier allows the dot to match across newline sequences.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you tried it with `replaceAll("<ref>.*</ref>", "");`. Try it with a questionmark, it makes the star non greedy. `replaceAll("<ref>.*?</ref>", "");`